What is the difference between Aspect Permissions and Stunts when it comes to determining what you can or can't do in a given situation?
In Fate, what is the difference between Aspect Permissions and Stunts when it comes to determining what you can or can't do in a given situation?
For example, the supplement "Super-Powered Fate" says an aspect like Invisible Man can be used to justify creating rolling to create a situational aspect called Invisible to justify rolling Stealth even in plain sight. How is that different from making a Stunt or invoking the First Aspect to just do that?

Potentially relevant discussions on Reddit: Aspect Permission vs stunts – and RPGnet: [FATE] Aspects vs. Stunts

The main difference is how concrete an advantage the character has in certain situations: a situation Aspect has to be created through a Create An Advantage roll that could fail, or at least cost Fate points to make succeed, while a Stunt is an always reliable thing the character can do (or at least attempt; there’s often still a roll involved). Whether you need either of those things, or if the Aspect itself is enough, depends on the specifics.
Broadly, if something is a core and permanent part of an Aspect, you probably don’t need anything else to represent it. (I think that’s the case with Invisible Man.)
If some kind of action or advantage is a smaller or optional or unreliable part of an Aspect - one possible use of a power like electromagnetic manipulation, say - then you can either use it to justify a Create An Advantage roll in play, in which case it’s not clear how well or even if it’ll work each time; or to justify the purchase of a Stunt which gives you access to a more reliable action. Often one can lead to the other: a Create An Advantage roll leads to something the character realises is super useful, so to represent them practising it or building some kind of reliable gadget etc they then buy the Stunt (or another Extra).
To go into more detail:
A character with the Aspect “Invisible Man” can be good at Stealth, and we’d expect it. In situations of low risk, you wouldn’t bother rolling - they can evade detection from normal folks just by standing still somewhere out of the way. And that would count for any Invisible Man character. I certainly wouldn’t make them roll to create an “Invisible” aspect in such a case. This is the usual use for the concept of Aspect permission: what the character can just do.
When in a stressful situation - evading trained operatives, or opponents who have special senses or equipment or who are just aware someone might be invisible, or maybe in the rain or other conditions that make being invisible less useful - then you need to roll to hide, even if you’re invisible. And, to be honest, I wouldn’t make them roll to create a situational Aspect at that point, either: invisible means invisible. Of course they can hide in plain sight - though they’ll need to do a good job to avoid leaving telltale signs (footprints, noises, a visible outline of raindrops etc) for skilled opponents.
At this point the character’s Stealth score becomes important: are they a professional or experienced hero, who’s trained in espionage? Are they a scientist who accidentally made themselves invisible, with no experience of hiding except in games as a kid? Either character might have used Invisible Man as a reason to buy a high Stealth skill, but probably the first one would have a higher score. Either can invoke Invisible Man to improve that Stealth roll, but one of them is probably relying on it, the other might not need it a lot of the time. And perhaps either of them can roll to Create An Advantage, but I don’t think “Invisible” is a good example:  being invisible is the point of the “Invisible Man” Aspect! They aren’t suddenly getting “more invisible”. And while the Aspect does have broader application, including some downsides (it implies the invisibility is always on, for example), primarily it means they’re invisible and making someone roll to get that benefit seems mean - as does making them take a stunt to hide in plain sight. It’s a fairly narrow Aspect, and this is a good but limited benefit it provides.
On the other hand, if they can actively use their invisibility in some unexpected way, or if it’s a power they have to activate - especially if it’s a broader power that might do more than one thing - then perhaps rolling to Create An Advantage or requiring a Stunt is justified. In this case the difference comes into play: do they want to take a risk and have to roll to create that Aspect when they need it? Or do they want it to be a reliable Stunt they can always use, paying the cost of refresh to have it?

What about aspect invokes, i.e paying a fate point...or us that similar to Create an Advantage,  only replace "possibility of failure" with "using resources"?

@blue289 Those don't seem to relate here. Invoking an aspect will benefit rolls, but don't interact with permission. (In early editions of the game you'd have to invoke an aspect for it to act as permission, but that's no longer the case since at least Fate Core.)

They're all different expressions of "invisibility as an Extra".
Whenever the mere fact of an Aspect means anything more than a transient narrative truth, or when you intend to spend Fate Points on it to create anything more than that or the +2 or reroll you're always allowed to, what you're doing is creating an Extra.
"Aspect Permission" has no meaning outside the context of an Extra. I'm not sure when the culture rose up that made it some kind of game mechanic in its own right, but it's really not. When someone says "my game makes use of Aspect Permission", what they actually mean is "my game uses Extras but we don't call them that" and maybe also "those Extras aren't really written down for common reference and nobody agrees on what they really mean".
What Isn't Extra: Transient Narrative Truth
This is a tool in your GM toolbox that I often call "the Advantage two-step" and isn't so much for building games as it is for running them. When you find yourself in a situation where what somebody is asking to do doesn't cleanly fit into "something one character could handle in one Overcome" or "something the PCs need to collectively face as a Challenge", and you don't want to just crank the Overcome number up real high to demand someone spend a Fate Point on making this a spotlight for themselves, take a moment, step back, ask yourself: is this something someone could handle in one Overcome if something else was true?
Once you have your "something else", that's the Advantage two-step. Somebody else Creates an Advantage to make an Aspect that makes it true, and your original asker can roll their Overcome. Using an Aspect in this way has several important elements:

The GM defines the mechanical hooks of this Aspect
the entire table understands what it's to be used for just from the explanation
the Aspect is put together ad-hoc for this scene and does not need to be relevant later

Whenever you want something more than this - you want the GM and players to work something out together, you're making something which has considerations people can't just understand by looking, you want something that will apply over a whole adventure or campaign - you're making an Extra.
Anatomy of an Extra: One Is Not Born But Rather Becomes Invisible
So, the concept of "being invisible" is an Extra. It's likely to be relevant at multiple points in a game, and the mechanical hooks and narrative capabilities should be worked out among the entire table. You can see some of this happening in the introduction to Super-Powered Fate (SPF), the Wearing the Cape supplementary rule book, trying to define how Invisible should work in play:

The GM could rule a gunman couldn't even try to shoot the Invisible character unless he had some way of creating a There You Are Aspect against him first (well, he could try, but failure at any real distance would be automatic). On the other hand, the Precog Sniper might know right where he needs to shoot to hit him.
-- "Superpower Creation", Super-Powered Fate p.4

Another part of making an Extra is deciding what game-mechanical elements it will impact and what costs it will have. Often these decisions will feed unto each other, and you'll wind up with costs like "acquire it with a Stunt" or "define it as an Aspect".
So how does a superpowered extra work in this system? A superpowered extra is defined as an Aspect and further abilities are decided at character creation; in the case of Invisible Man this means the ability to use Will to create the Invisible aspect, which itself is going to get some definition in terms of further game capabilities. What does this all mean?

the exact extent of any given Extra is defined during collaborative character creation, rather than being known to everyone in advance. This is fine, since character creation is happening with everybody together, and everybody gets "one personal superpower" so the GM just has to worry about balancing character capabilities against each other.
the superpower Extra is linked to an Aspect, meaning people are already considering Aspect collision when they're thinking about the powers they pick for themselves.
the Invisible Man is not invisible all the time; this is modeled by the presence or absence of an Invisible aspect, which he is uniquely able to create; as part of the Extra creation, the GM adds an additional capability to the Invisible Man's Will skill.
unless they take a relevant power Aspect, no other PC in the game will be able to turn invisible.

I can't say anything about whether these are the right decisions or the best decisions, but they're the decisions these authors chose to make and these are what they mean. Other authors have made different ones.
Super Pick-n-Mix: Invisibility as Stunt
Venture City Chronicles (VCC) gives starting characters three additional picks of "power stunts", which can be used to select basic common powers or expand powers they already have. One of these powers is:

Basic Invisibility: You can completely fade from view, including your clothes and anything you’re carrying. Cameras and similar devices cannot detect you at all, and you gain +2 to Stealth against being seen by living targets.
-- "Powers Catalogue", VCC p. 44

This assumes the character can become reflexively invisible whenever it would be relevant, without the need to manage it through an Aspect. VCC has a prebuilt selection of component power stunts that it intends for characters to combine to create a thematic suite of powers; a hero who can turn into a shadow creature might get some basic invisibility as a result, or a hero who turns invisible might also be able to phase through matter.
Dresden Files Accelerated (DFA) uses a similar gating mechanism on its invisibility-like power, with it being a stunt that's a core function of a feature of the Fae mantle, Glamour, which lets characters use their Intellect to shroud something in invisibility or another visual illusion. Anybody who wants to be a Fae has the ability to turn things invisible.
In both of these cases, invisibility is a freely pickable power by any character, which operates under a previously defined set of limitations. But also in both of these cases, characters are intended to have more than just one power aspect - VCC characters are intended to be an assemblage of different basic powers, and DFA mantles are similarly intended to grant a variety of possible abilities (at least when they're supernatural). Both of these intended uses fit the idea of something pickable in multiples, and a stunt matches that.
Why Not Invoke For Invisibility?
Well, first, because that's not how invoking works. Invoking an aspect is a purely mechanical exercise; after you've rolled the dice, it gets you a +2 or a reroll.
Using a Fate Point to declare a related story detail is probably also not a good model for invisibility, at least as it relates to the Invisible Man aspect. That sort of thing is more for, well, transient narrative truths, things that are only going to arise in the moment. If you could take on an inhuman form that blended in well with a particular environment you happened to encounter, that'd be more the sort of thing spending a Fate Point on a story detail would cover. You know the Invisible Man is going to turn invisible at some point, you probably don't want to leave it up to in-the-moment spackle.
You could also be thinking about using "spend a Fate Point" as a cost for an Extra, similar to the way SPF handles its duplication power example: the character with a duplication power can spend a Fate Point to enter any scene they weren't established in because a duplicate wandered over there, or exit any scene they were established in because that was actually a duplicate which is now gone. However, keep in mind that characters aren't likely to get even a double-digit number of Fate Points during a game session, meaning that using a Fate Point should be a bit of a spotlight moment for them. The duplicator can do other things besides appear and disappear from scenes, but invisibility is the Invisible Man's only trick. Demanding a Fate Point every time they use their powers probably isn't going to be fair to them, relative to the other PCs.
